# Intergrating Google Pay in a bottom sheet in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-pay

I was wondering whether it is possible including Google Pay within an app (in this case, a launcher). The plan is to place this inside a bottom sheet so that it can be pulled up for instant access. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Pay uses UPI to transfer money so you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/upi_india) plugin or [this](https://pub.dev/packages?q=upi). Personally, I recommend [razorpay](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this